# Help asked for iPhone and Android app

Tags: iphone, android

Im new to the development of apps and i've got some questions.

First let me tell you about the app i need to make.
As an intern at a company i need to develop an iPhone and Android app, they want me to create an app that is based on a existing CRM database.
I need to get data from the database and show it on the iPhone, this data should be edited and send back to the database.
The company itself does not has experience in the development of mobile apps.

EDIT:
The requirements i wrote above are the basic of the application, it will have alot more functionality implemented after the basic has been made. Something like an auto sync, either the database or phone will sync with each other once in a while. And when you are called on the phone it will also check the number in the database and if found the name is displayed instead of an unknow number. Just 2 things that should be implemented after the basic app

- Is such a thing possible with an iPhone/Android?

As i have no experience with Objective-C, and little experience with java

- Is it easy to learn, i have good knowledge of C#
- What platform could you suggest for me?

As i need to develop for both iPhone and Android,

- What is the quickest way of developing for both at the same time?

i've done research but as i do not have an mac at the moment i can't try stuff out for the iPhone.
Titanium Appcelerator is something i liked, and since this works for both iPhone and Android i think this might be a good option. But as i do not have any experience i want some good advice from those who have experience before i start programming.

tnx in advance,
~kamikze the rookie

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/about).
You can use web services to connect to databases

Comment: havent found this one yet, ill have a look into it. But if i remember corretly this will make a browser app or a regular app?

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirements, use Titanium Appcelarator, which will make you write your code in JavaScript, and will generate apps for both, iPhone and Android.

What you're wanting it to do is fairly simple and shouldn't introduce a lot of complexity before you.

Go ahead with [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/), if you don't want to spend a lot of time learning Android SDK and Objectiv-C

Comment: The requirements i wrote above are the basic of the application, it will have alot more functionality implemented after the basic has been made.

Something like an auto sync, either the database or phone will sync with each other once in a while. And when you are called on the phone it will also check the number in the database and if found the name is displayed instead of an unknow number.

Just 2 things that should be implemented after the basic app

Comment: Well, all that can be done with Android SDK, but I don't have any knowledge of Objective-C. I am just not into iOS dev. I am unaware of Appcelerator's new powers, as I haven't used it since a while.

Answer (score 0):

It sure is possible to access/change databases.
If you have good C# knowledge then getting started with Java should not be an issue for you.

I think it should be quite easy to implement for Android, but I also have no experience in iOS development (don´t have a mac)

Comment: the java language should not be a problem, its just that making an good working interface is like trying to read korean or something.